# Append Xml a given number of times

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

I am appending to an existing xml file:  The code is below: I am using C# .net 4.5 VS 2012 and creating a WPF application.

How could I append this say 30 times and only change D100 attribute number to 2,3,4,5 etc?
The other values are the same!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml;

namespace AppendX
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("C:\\Temp.xml");

            XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            namespaces.AddNamespace("flp", "http://www.w3.org/2001/flp");



            XmlNode nextNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/flp:Tab/flp:Designs", namespaces);

            XmlElement D100 = doc.CreateElement("flp", "D100", "http://www.w3.org/2001/flp");
            D100.SetAttribute("Number", "2");

            XmlElement Code = doc.CreateElement("flp", "Code", "http://www.w3.org/2001/flp");
            Code.InnerText = "B";
            D100.AppendChild(Code);

            XmlElement Documented = doc.CreateElement("flp", "Documented", "http://www.w3.org/2001/flp");
            Documented.InnerText = "false";
            D100.AppendChild(Documented);

            nextNode.AppendChild(D100);

            doc.Save("test1.xml");



        }
    }
}
```

Here is the sample xml I am using, sorry I meant to put this up!

```
<flp:Tab xmlns:flp="http://www.w3.org/2001/flp"   Title="Testing">
  <flp:Form Number="0" id="1005" />
  <flp:Rev Time="2013-01-21T15:08:00">
    <flp:Author Name="Brad" Aid="15" />
  </flp:Rev>
  <flp:Designs Id="D100">
    <flp:D100 Number="1">
      <flp:Code>A</flp:Code>
      <flp:Documented>true</flp:Documented>
    </flp:D100>
  </flp:Designs>
</flp:Tab>
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlDocument`? LINQ to XML ends up being much simpler code. Even if you *do* have to use `XmlDocument`, which have you tried in the way of looping? It looks like you can probably just put a loop around the code starting with `XmlElement D100 = ...` and ending with `nextNode.AppendChild(D100);`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate private function that would handle the creation of the document element, given the parameters.  ex:

```
private xmlelement dothework(string param1, string param2){

    'do all necessary work to set up the element in here and then return it

}
```

I would separate the work like this, create a different function for each section of work, so that eventually you can just loop through and append each to the document.